# Undeletable or persistent docker-compose volumes or data storage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

is there possible to somehow create persistent storage for containers, created with docker-compose and don't remove them even when running `docker-compose down -v` so they will be automaticly attached to their containers after again starting the `docker-compose up -d` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to use an external volume, something like:

```
$ docker volume create nodemodules
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:11
    volumes:
      - nodemodules:/app/node_modules

volumes:
  nodemodules:
    external: true
```

Refer the docs for more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external